# Библиотека для работы с математическими графами

Tags: c#, математика, winforms, .net

Уточняю, графы - это те, которые используют в математике, у них есть вершины и ребра. Прежде всего интересует компонент для визуализации графов, а не компонент для их описания. 
Нужно чтобы работало в обычном winforms-приложении.

Answer (score 4):

- [GLEE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx) + [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)
- [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) (на основе WPF)

При необходимости WPF-контрол можно хостить внутри WinForms

Comment: Попробую с GLEE разобраться, спасибо.  
С Graph# не понял как его на форме разместить, там как я понял, нужен 4-й фреймворк.

Comment: ... а лучше не насиловать труп WinForms и писать сразу на чистом и светлом WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Ресурсов довольно много. Вот аналогичный вопрос со [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578493/net-graph-library-around)

- [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)
- [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Ну как бы я видел вопрос на stackoverflow, но легче от ответов не стало. <br> 
`Graph#` похоже не заставить работать из-за отсутствия WPF, `QuickGraph` - это вообще только матем. описание графов,  
попробую `NodeXL`.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще [`GraphX`](http://graphx.codeplex.com) но тоже на `WPF. WinForms` для работы с графикой и отображением это сущий кошмар. Хотя можно покошмарить еще больше и использовать `Interop` для встраивания `WPF` в `WinForms` :)